# how to get 2nd field from textfile in Spark(using scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce

I am trying to convert my MapReduce code to spark using Scala. and not able to extract 2nd field from comma delimited input. I tried multiple options but not getting it to run successfully. it compiles OK but throws a runtime exception: `scala.MatchError: MapPartitionsRDD[2]`

Any hint will be helpful:

**Input:**

```
 Australia,6,2,7690,15,1,1,0,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,blue,0,1,1,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,white,blue
 Austria,3,1,84,8,4,0,0,3,2,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,red,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,red,red
 Bahamas,1,4,19,0,1,1,0,3,3,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,blue,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,blue,blue
```

**Mapper:**

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String [] flags = value.toString().split(",");
            switch(flags[1]){
            case "1": landmass.set("N.America"); break;
            case "2": landmass.set("S.America"); break;
            case "3": landmass.set("Europe"); break;
            case "4": landmass.set("Africa"); break;
            case "5": landmass.set("Asia"); break;
            case "6": landmass.set("Oceania");break;
            }
            context.write(landmass, new Text(flags[0]));
        }
```

**Spark(Scala):**

```
 object countriesByLandmass {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val inputFile = "Data\\country\\flag.data"

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Total Countries by Landmass").setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val txtFileLines = sc.textFile(inputFile).cache()

    //val fields = txtFileLines.flatMap(_.split(","))

   // fields.foreach(value => println(value))

    val fields = txtFileLines.map(_.split(",")(1))

    val landmass = fields.toString() match {
    case "1"  => "N.America"
    case "2"  => "S.America"
    case "3"  => "Europe"
    case "4"  => "Africa"
    case "5"  => "Asia"
    case "6"  => "Oceania"
    }

   println(landmass)
  }
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at countriesByLandmass.scala:22 (of class java.lang.String)
    at com.country.countriesByLandmass$.main(countriesByLandmass.scala:24)
    at com.country.countriesByLandmass.main(countriesByLandmass.scala)
```

**[UPDATED] Solution:**

```
val fields = txtFileLines.map(_.split(",")(1)).foreach{ lm_code => 
    val landmass = lm_code match {
    case "1"  => "N.America"
    case "2"  => "S.America"
    case "3"  => "Europe"
    case "4"  => "Africa"
    case "5"  => "Asia"
    case "6"  => "Oceania"
    case _    => "Invalid Code"
    } 
     println(lm_code + " --> " + landmass)
    }
```

Comment: The **fields.toString** is the object name of your RDD object, and since it is not matching with one of your six options, it is throwing the error. Please see my answer for more detail, how to fix this.

Comment: Edited: Scala code with answer

Comment: If you edit your question in this way no one will understand what was the problem. Please keep the original question. The visitors will find the best answer using the votes.

Comment: If you want, append the solution at the end of your question

Comment: Thanks, appended solution. . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems here

1. The value **fields** is a RDD, a spark collection with all the second columns in your data. Then you need to convert your data inside a Map.

   ```
   val fields = txtFileLines.map(_.split(",")(1)).map { col2 =>
     val landmass = col2 match {
       case "1"  => "N.America"
       case "2"  => "S.America"
       case "3"  => "Europe"
       case "4"  => "Africa"
       case "5"  => "Asia"
       case "6"  => "Oceania"
     }
     println(landmass)
   }
   ```
  2.

In Java if you don´t specify a **default** case, and the input doesn´t match with one option, then the input is ignored and not code is executed without an exception.

In Scala if the input doesn´t match an option an error is thrown. A MatchError to be more accurate.

To avoid this you can specify a default value in the follow way:

```
val landmass = col2 match {
  case "1"  => "N.America"
  case "2"  => "S.America"
  case "3"  => "Europe"
  case "4"  => "Africa"
  case "5"  => "Asia"
  case "6"  => "Oceania"
  case _    => "Invalid option"
}
```

Comment: adding default case resolved the MatchError, I had to use foreach instead of map  

    `val fields = txtFileLines.map(_.split(",")(1)).foreach{ lm_code => 
    val landmass = lm_code match {. . .`

Comment: If the answer helped you to resolve your problem please accept the answer.